# How can I get class names back when using MultiLabelBinarizer

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I have a csv file which looks like this:

```
target,data
AAA,some text document
AAA;BBB,more text
AAC,more text
```

Here is the code:

```
from sklearn.multiclass import OneVsRestClassifier
from sklearn.preprocessing import MultiLabelBinarizer
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import HashingVectorizer
from sklearn.naive_bayes import BernoulliNB
import pandas as pd

pdf = pd.read_csv("Train.csv", sep=',')
pdfT = pd.read_csv("Test.csv", sep=',')

X1 = pdf['data']
Y1 = [[t for t in tar.split(';')] for tar in pdf['target']]
X2 = pdfT['data']
Y2 = [[t for t in tar.split(';')] for tar in pdfT['target']]

# Vectorizer data
hv = HashingVectorizer(stop_words='english', non_negative=True)
X1 = hv.transform(X1)
X2 = hv.transform(X2)

mlb = MultiLabelBinarizer()
mlb.fit(Y1+Y2)
Y1 = mlb.transform(Y1)
# mlb.classes_ looks like ['AAA','AAC','BBB',...]  len(mlb.classes_)==1363

# Y1 looks like [[0,0,0,....0,0,0], ... ] now

# fit
clsf = OneVsRestClassifier(BernoulliNB(alpha=.001))
clsf.fit(X1,Y1)

# predict_proba
proba = clsf.predict_proba(X2)

# want to get class names back
classnames = mlb.inverse_transform(clsf.classes_) # booom, shit happens

for i in range(len(proba)):
    # get classnames,probability dict
    preDict = dict(zip(classnames, proba[i]))
    # sort dict by probability value, print actual and top 5 predict results
    print(Y2[i], dict(sorted(preDict.items(),key=lambda d:d[1],reverse=True)[0:5]))
```

The problem is after clsf.fit(X1,Y1)
clsf.classes_ is an int array [0,1,2,3,...1362]

why is it not like Y1? How can I get the classnames from clsf.classes_? mlb.classes_ == clsf.classes_ or not, with same order?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you fit `OneVsRestClassifier` with multiple labels a `LabelBinarizer` is called during the `fit` call, which will convert the the multilabels into unique labels for each class.

You can access the `label_binarizer_` attribute of the `clsf` object, which has an attribute for classes that will contain the class definition for classes fit in the call to `clsf`.

Comment: thank you!  `label_binarizer_` is what I need
`bitarray = clsf.label_binarizer_.inverse_transform(proba, threshold=0.5)` 
then
`classnames = mlb.inverse_transform(bitarray)`
but the clsf.predict_proba(X2) seems return probabilities on each binary

Comment: for instance , `firstResut = mlb.inverse_transform(np.array[ bitarray[0] ])` which is  `[('AAA','BBB',)]`  , how I get probability for each lable in there ?